# AWS Cognito permissions to access S3 on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm developing an Android app and keep having issues accessing S3 bucket "through" Cognito.
I'm managing to connect to my cognito pool, with a username and a password of a specific user from my pool:

```
AWSMobileClient auth = AWSMobileClient.getInstance();
auth.signIn("username", "password", new HashMap<String, String>());
if (auth.isSignedIn()) {
        ActivityUtils.startActivity(this, MyActivity.class);
}
```

My user in the pool is assigned to a group with attach S3 role:

```
Role ARN    arn:aws:iam::<my account number>:role/Cognito_S3_Full_Access
```

Which contains those permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I'm trying to use the "AmazonS3Client" I created using the credentials from the "AWSMobileClient" I keep getting errors. I create it in this way:

```
AWSMobileClient awsMobileClient =AWSMobileClient.getInstance();
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsMobileClient);
```

And the **error that I got is**:

```
2019-05-20 17:56:21.645 27019-27019/com.mycomp.mypackage E/S3Uploader: Error upload file to S3 bucket : Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 375C07384A904483)
```

When I'm creating the "AmazonS3Client" using **HARD-CODED** accessKey and secretKey of a new "IAM" user that I created and attach the same policy as above it working as expected.
I'm using it this way:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("myAccessKey_hsjgfhjsdg", "mySecretKey_asdhasjkdha");
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

But I don't want to fill up my app with hard coded password, especially that I already manage to connect using the user input of his username and password

- Some notes: when I trying to get the secret key and access key after login with Cognito I can see that I get different token every login, so I guess this part is working.

So my question is what am I doing wrong?

How can I make the "AmazonS3Client" to use the session and role permission of the log-in user and his assigned group?

Comment: there is a minor bug in your code. Fixing this minor bug that exists in your code will make it work.

Comment: Mind to share where is the bug?

Comment: Hello, does your Authenticated Role in Cognito have enough permissions to get data from S3? Did you test the flow via the AWS CLI?

Comment: `AWSMobileClient awsMobileClient =AWSMobileClient.getInstance();
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsMobileClient);` is located inside `MyActivity`?

Comment: @Zdendek - Yes it is.

Comment: @Arka yes they have, I didn't test the flow via CLI. Not sure how exactly I can do it.

Comment: InitiateAuth -> Get Token -> Use Token in Logins Map for GetID and GetCredentialsForIdentity -> Use the Creds in the ~/.aws/configure file. Let me know the result of this test.

Answer (score 0):

I had everything set up properly and was getting the same **Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 8D650E2CCCD58E34)**

What I missed was the condition in the S3 template:

```
"Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
        "s3:prefix": [
            "public/",
            "public/*",
            "protected/",
            "protected/*",
            "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/",
            "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Basically your keys have to start with these prefixes, depending on the policy. I didn't think much of the **public/s3Key.txt** example key in the Amplify docs.

```
private val transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
    .context(context)
    .s3Client(AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance(), Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)))
    .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration) // use the generated s3 template
    .build()

transferUtility.upload("public/$key/${file.name}", file)
```